# fluent-nHinernate TriggerIdentity nhIdOutParam always return null (Oracle rdbms)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I using Oracle rdbms.
My mapping looks like this
 `Id(x => x.Tid,"ID").Column("ID").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();`

but the SQL request ends up looking like:

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO bla bla bla :nhIdOutParam = NULL [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Why does `nhIdOutParam`  always return **null** value?

fluent-nHibernate version is 1.2.0.712. nHibernate version is 3.1.0.4000

Comment: i thought this would work for oracle, but won't for Postgresql. the insert ends with `returning nhIdOutParam` which assignes the generated id to this out parameter

Answer (score 0):

i thought this would work for oracle, but won't for Postgresql. the insert ends with returning nhIdOutParam which assignes the generated id to this out parameter.

as pseudocode

```
command.CommandText = sql + " return nhIdOutParam";
command.Parameter.Add(new Parameter { Name = "nhIdOutParam", Type = outparam, Value = 0 });
command.Execute();

returnedId = command.Parameter["nhIdOutParam"].Value;
```